# How to draw four images in circle quarterly equal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I need to draw four group images in a circle quarterly equal. 
can anyone help me below is the screen

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `view`,for example 200*200

Then add 4 `imageviw` to this view

Then set `cornerRadius`

```
self.testview.layer.cornerRadius = 100;
self.testview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I just set background color,it looks like this

[image]

Comment: nice , It is very simple, why I could not think like this .

Comment: Leo how I could do for 3 , 2 images like facebook do for groups also some times images are rectangle shape not covering complete circle also if image don't have white background ? give you thought please

Answer (score 3):

You can follow these steps to achieve this.
 In create a view in .xib according to attach image. I have created a view "imageViewHolder". which have four UIImageView. Since I have all four image with white background so I have used 2 label with black color and used them as line separator bitween images. U can use any color according to your requirement.

[image: see .xib screen shot]

set IBoutlet to ImageViewHolder
edit below code according to your requirement

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
// first make imageViewHolder round

[self getRoundCollage];
```

}

```
-(UIImage *)getRoundCollage{
// first make imageViewHolder as circular view
self.imageViewHolder.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageViewHolder.frame.size.width/2;
self.imageViewHolder.clipsToBounds = YES;

// now take screen shot of imageView

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageViewHolder.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.imageViewHolder.layer renderInContext:context];



UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

}

see result [image: result]

If u like my answer. Then do not forget to vote my answer

Comment: appreciate ur work if you could make images not to be clipped but Leo answer is very simple and convenient u deserved an up vote.